# How to pass the id to next page dynamically instead of passing statically

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my application i need to pass the id from one page to another page i tried using session but it gives me id as null can anyone provide the other ways to do this

```
GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
string ticketid = item["ID"].Text;
Session["viewID"] = ticketid;
Response.Redirect("View.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // you check if the item["ID"] is null?
    string ticketid = item["ID"].Text;
    // are you making sure you are not overiding this session variable some place on the page
    Session["viewID"] = ticketid;
// this should get the id on the query string if you don't want to use session.
Response.Redirect(String.Format("View.aspx?ViewID={0}", ticketid));
```